# Bought Windows 8 OEM, how to reinstall fresh?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, iso-image, oem

With Windows 7 my PC had a product key on the back. I was able to go to DigitalRiver and download the ISO. My PC did not have a product key listed but I was able to use BelArc to get it. I tried downloading the Win8 Enterprise off the MSDN clone site however I could not activate it. I'm having trouble finding the ISOs, or a Windows 8 home edition for that matter.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do and what's your question?

Comment: The reason Windows 8 Enterprise didn't activate is because you don't have a Windows 8 Enterprise license.  Windows 8 and Windows 8 Professional are both on MSDN and Dreamspark. You have to install the right version of Windows 8, since only you have that information, only you can solve that problem.

Comment: My question is where are the ISOs for Windows 8 standard edition?  MyDigitalRiver used to have all the official legal ISOs from Microsoft.

Comment: You shouldn't use double spaces after sentences, BTW. Edited to fix.

Comment: Windows 8 OEM != Windows 8 Enterprise. You're probably looking for a standard Windows 8 installation disc. I'm pretty sure the only difference between standard Windows 8 and standard Windows 8 OEM are the licensing terms.

Answer (score 2):

get a MSDN/Technet ISO (`en_windows_8_x64_dvd.iso`) and simply install Windows 8.

This ISO will use the embedded OEM key from the MSDM table of your UEFI.